# How to set custom Interpolator programatically in MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout, android-motionscene

I have created some animations with MotionLyout using the Android Studio design tool, so everything is under the layout xml and the scene xml files. In one transition I used the `motion:motionInterpolator="bounce"` configuration but I don't like the way it bounces (4 times bouncing). So I am considering creating my custom bounce `Interpolator` but I cannot find a way to set this interpolator programatically, like we can do with the `AnimationUtils` lib:

```
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale).apply {
    interpolator = CustomBounceInterpolator()
    viewToAnimate.startAnimation(this)
}
```

Is there a way to set this custom interpolator programatically in `MotionLayout`?